# At least one security token in the message could not be validated

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, certificate, wshttpbinding

**Server config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehavior">
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="cn=cool" storeName="TrustedPeople" storeLocation="CurrentUser" />
                </serviceCredentials>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehavior" name="Service">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageAndUserName" name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint" contract="IService"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MessageAndUserName">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

**My client config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="LocalCertValidation">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser" />
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" >
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:48097/WCFServer/Service.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
                  contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                  name="WSHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="LocalCertValidation">
            <identity>
                <dns value ="cool" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Service:**

```
public string TestAccess()
{
    return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

**Client:**

```
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Admin";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123";
        Console.WriteLine(client.TestAccess());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

**Error:**
An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
**Inner exception:**
At least one security token in the message could not be validated.

How do I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the problem is your user name and password. With default configuration user name and password is validated as windows account. If you want other validation you must either use [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) or [custom user name password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i worked at this simple example 1 week, without your help i would work more. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Since the error message is rather obscure, thought I would put it out there as another possible solution.

My environment uses Single Sign On (or STS if you prefer) to authenticate a user through ASP.NET MVC site. MVC site in turn makes a service call to my service endpoint by passing bearer token which it requested from STS server with Bootstrap token previously. The error I got was when I made a service call from MVC site.

In my case, this is caused by my Service's configuration as stated below. Particularly audienceUris node, it must exactly match the service endpoint:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
        <audienceUris>
            <add value="https://localhost/IdpExample.YService/YService.svc" />
        </audienceUris>
        ....
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

HTH.